# vue.js render a list in array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have a instance of Vue.js that make a fetch GET request and i want to display all the data using [v-for](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) but i can access the field that i want inside the jsonBody requisition.

**My instance of vue.js:**

```
var pedidosTable = new Vue({
    el: '#pedidosTable',
    data: function(){
        return{
            listOfDi: [],
            listOfStep1: []    
        }
    },
    created: function(){   
        const req = fetch("http://localhost:4242/api/v1/dis").then(response =>{
            return response.json();
       }).then(jsonBody =>{
                this.listOfDi = jsonBody;
           });  
    },
    methods:{
      
    },
    
});
```

**my HTML:**

```
 <tr v-for="item of listOfDi">
     <td>{{ item.DI.Step1[0].nomeDoCliente }}</td>
 </tr>
```

**My json in the fetch request:**

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5f4608e4516d5c137e9d40e7",
      "DI":{
         "Step1":[
            {
               "codigoCliente":"56777",
               "operacao":"PRÓPRIA",
               "tipoDeOperacao":"TRADING",
               "lucro":"REAL",
               "beneficioIpi":"NÃO",
               "consumidor":"P. JURÍDICA",
               "rateio":"PESO",
               "nomeDoCliente":"Submarino",
               "dolarDi":4.4359,
               "dolarCambio":4.5
            }
         ],
         "Step2":[
            {
               "id":{
                  "oid":"5f232394ac7e930548107d16"
               },
               "produto":"cadeira de rodas",
               "ncm":"467.987",
               "descricao":"cadeira de rodas teste",
               "cliente_id":{
                  "oid":"5f21e23eac7e9305490f9424"
               },
               "aliqII":0.2,
               "aliqIpi":0,
               "aliqPis":0.21,
               "aliqCofins":0.0965,
               "pesoUnitario":0.43,
               "unitario":0.88,
               "dumping":0,
               "cubagemUnitario":0,
               "quantidade":33,
               "icmEstadoDestino":0,
               "mvaAjustado":0,
               "markup":0.12,
               "selected":true,
               "url":"http://localhost:3000/produtos/5f232394ac7e930548107d16.json"
            },
            {
               "id":{
                  "oid":"5f232c61ac7e930a6f8ea06a"
               },
               "produto":"Bicicleta",
               "ncm":"456.879",
               "descricao":"Bicicleta caloi",
               "cliente_id":{
                  "oid":"5f21e23eac7e9305490f9424"
               },
               "aliqII":0.2,
               "aliqIpi":0,
               "aliqPis":0.21,
               "aliqCofins":0.0965,
               "pesoUnitario":0.43,
               "unitario":0.78,
               "dumping":0,
               "cubagemUnitario":0,
               "quantidade":44,
               "icmEstadoDestino":0,
               "mvaAjustado":0,
               "markup":0.12,
               "selected":true,
               "url":"http://localhost:3000/produtos/5f232c61ac7e930a6f8ea06a.json"
            }
         ],
         "Step3":[
            {
               "freteInternacional":1790.36,
               "capatazia":384.35,
               "siscomex":260.1,
               "marinhaMercante":2076.97,
               "outrasDespesasAduaneiras":1000
            }
         ],
         "Step4":[
            {
               "armazenagemZonaPrimaria":2986,
               "diferencaFreteInternacional":158.09,
               "despachante":1835.68,
               "liStep4":53.53,
               "taxasBl":844.05,
               "tarifaCambial":250,
               "multa":0,
               "taxaExpediente":250,
               "freteAoCliente":1194,
               "debitoIcms":0.04,
               "pagEfetivo":0.04,
               "pagDesembaraco":0.01,
               "descontoComercial":0.01,
               "debitoPIS":0.0165,
               "debitoCofins":0.076,
               "IR":0.25,
               "CSLL":0.09
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "_id":"5f460d55f46a2b160079f9a8",
      "DI":{
         "Step1":[
            {
               "codigoCliente":"98978",
               "operacao":"PRÓPRIA",
               "tipoDeOperacao":"TRADING",
               "lucro":"REAL",
               "beneficioIpi":"NÃO",
               "consumidor":"P. JURÍDICA",
               "rateio":"PESO",
               "nomeDoCliente":"Black & Decker",
               "dolarDi":4.4359,
               "dolarCambio":4.5
            }
         ],
         "Step2":[
            {
               "id":{
                  "oid":"5f077925ac7e9319ff7d1c6b"
               },
               "produto":"cafeteira",
               "ncm":"9878.7389",
               "descricao":"cafeteira capsula",
               "cliente_id":{
                  "oid":"5f0775e8ac7e9319ff7d1c68"
               },
               "aliqII":0.2,
               "aliqIpi":0,
               "aliqPis":0.21,
               "aliqCofins":0.0965,
               "pesoUnitario":0.43,
               "unitario":0.78,
               "dumping":0,
               "cubagemUnitario":0,
               "quantidade":12,
               "icmEstadoDestino":0,
               "mvaAjustado":0,
               "markup":0.12,
               "selected":true,
               "url":"http://localhost:3000/produtos/5f077925ac7e9319ff7d1c6b.json"
            }
         ],
         "Step3":[
            {
               "freteInternacional":1790.36,
               "capatazia":384.35,
               "siscomex":260.1,
               "marinhaMercante":2076.97,
               "outrasDespesasAduaneiras":1000
            }
         ],
         "Step4":[
            {
               "armazenagemZonaPrimaria":2986,
               "diferencaFreteInternacional":158.09,
               "despachante":1835.68,
               "liStep4":53.53,
               "taxasBl":844.05,
               "tarifaCambial":250,
               "multa":0,
               "taxaExpediente":250,
               "freteAoCliente":1194,
               "debitoIcms":0.04,
               "pagEfetivo":0.04,
               "pagDesembaraco":0.01,
               "descontoComercial":0.01,
               "debitoPIS":0.0165,
               "debitoCofins":0.076,
               "IR":0.25,
               "CSLL":0.09
            }
         ],
      }
   }
]
```

How can i acess and display the field `nomeDoCliente` inside the `Step1` array in my v-for list?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: FYI, your JSON is invalid. You have a trailing comma after `Step4` in the second object

Comment: try putting a `catch` block in fetch call as well. if anything will go wrong while API call it will display it inside console with the trace. Also I am little bit unclear why you are assigning the fetch call to `req` in `created` lifecycle.

Comment: @Phil vue.self-c01aa728f5ddebda3ce1631ce969813377a484b0d08f9ffab9bfc39317896a5f.js?body=1:1898 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Step1' of undefined

Comment: @sunnyprakash why don't show the field in the v-for?

Comment: Then your JSON response is not what you think it is. Have you tried adding `console.log(jsonBody)` to double check?

Comment: Also, the JSON in your question is still invalid

Comment: @Phil I tried many many times, `console.log(jsonBody` and it works fine, but i cant access the `Step1`

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonBody, null, 2))`, copy the result and paste it exactly as it appears into your question

Comment: @MatheusBarem I tried mimicking the problem statement in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-demo-vyz9l and the expression `{{item.DI.Step1[0].nomeDoCliente}}` is rendering properly. Go through it, see if it helps. Also i would request you to render `{{listOfDi}}` inside your HTML just like i did in codesandbox. If json body is same as above then it will definitely print out.